# how to check ray intersection with object in ARCore

Tags: android, arcore

Is there a way to check if I touched the object on the screen ? As I understand the HitResult class allows me to check if I touched the recognized and maped surface. But I want to check this I touched the object that is set on that surface.

Answer (score 4):

ARCore doesn't really have a concept of an object, so we can't directly provide that.  I suggest looking at [ray-sphere tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection) for a starting point.

However, I can help with getting the ray itself (to be added to `HelloArActivity`):

```
/** 
 * Returns a world coordinate frame ray for a screen point.  The ray is
 * defined using a 6-element float array containing the head location
 * followed by a normalized direction vector.
 */
float[] screenPointToWorldRay(float xPx, float yPx, Frame frame) {
    float[] points = new float[12];  // {clip query, camera query, camera origin}
    // Set up the clip-space coordinates of our query point
    // +x is right:
    points[0] = 2.0f * xPx / mSurfaceView.getMeasuredWidth() - 1.0f;
    // +y is up (android UI Y is down):
    points[1] = 1.0f - 2.0f * yPx / mSurfaceView.getMeasuredHeight(); 
    points[2] = 1.0f; // +z is forwards (remember clip, not camera)
    points[3] = 1.0f; // w (homogenous coordinates)

    float[] matrices = new float[32];  // {proj, inverse proj}
    // If you'll be calling this several times per frame factor out
    // the next two lines to run when Frame.isDisplayRotationChanged().
    mSession.getProjectionMatrix(matrices, 0, 1.0f, 100.0f);
    Matrix.invertM(matrices, 16, matrices, 0);
    // Transform clip-space point to camera-space.
    Matrix.multiplyMV(points, 4, matrices, 16, points, 0);
    // points[4,5,6] is now a camera-space vector.  Transform to world space to get a point
    // along the ray.
    float[] out = new float[6];
    frame.getPose().transformPoint(points, 4, out, 3);
    // use points[8,9,10] as a zero vector to get the ray head position in world space.
    frame.getPose().transformPoint(points, 8, out, 0);
    // normalize the direction vector:
    float dx = out[3] - out[0];
    float dy = out[4] - out[1];
    float dz = out[5] - out[2];
    float scale = 1.0f / (float) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
    out[3] = dx * scale;
    out[4] = dy * scale;
    out[5] = dz * scale;
    return out;
}
```

If you're calling this several times per frame see the comment about the `getProjectionMatrix` and `invertM` calls.

Comment: first of all thank you for you answer. My concern is that on the web I am able to find a lot of different examples of ray intersection with simple objects, what with more complex objects?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [Mouse Picking with Ray Casting](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html), cf. Ian's answer, the other commonly used technique is a picking buffer, explained in detail (with C++ code) [here](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial29/tutorial29.html)

> The trick behind 3D picking is very simple. We will attach a running
>   index to each triangle and have the FS output the index of the
>   triangle that the pixel belongs to. The end result is that we get a
>   "color" buffer that doesn't really contain colors. Instead, for each
>   pixel which is covered by some primitive we get the index of this
>   primitive. When the mouse is clicked on the window we will read back
>   that index (according to the location of the mouse) and render the
>   select triangle red. By combining a depth buffer in the process we
>   guarantee that when several primitives are overlapping the same pixel
>   we get the index of the top-most primitive (closest to the camera).

So in a nutshell:

1. Every object's draw method needs an ongoing index and a boolean for whether this draw renders the pixel buffer or not.
2. The render method converts the index into a grayscale color and the scene is rendered
3. After the whole rendering is done, retrieve the pixel color at the touch position `GL11.glReadPixels(x, y, /*the x and y of the pixel you want the colour of*/)`. Then translate the color back to an index and the index back to an object. Voilà, you have your clicked object.

To be fair, for a mobile usecase you should probably read a 10x10 rectangle, iterate trough it and pick the first found non-background color - because touches are never that precise.

This approach works independently of the complexity of your objects

[image: Click Buffer example]

Comment: yeah but it work with simple objects with couple of colors. When you`re outdoor and you will use green color for the object than it is easy for wrong interpretation (for example grass, tree)

Comment: No, you can render your whole scene with "wrong" colos, i.e. no lighting, no textures,... just a fixed color for each object (cf. the screenshot I added above). This image is never shown to the user and is just used to determine the click

Comment: So I would have 2 layers ? One with "wrong" colors, and the second one visible for the user ?

Comment: Yes, if "layer" is an informal phrase here (the formal one could be "buffer"). And the "wrong-color-layer" is only rendered when a click was made.