# ARCore object tracking without a plane

Tags: java, arcore

I am very new to this ARCore and I have been looking at the HelloAR Java Android Studio project provided in the SDK.

Everthing works OK and is pretty cool, however, I want to place/drop an object when I touch the screen even when no planes have been detected. Let me explain a little better...

As I understand ARCore, it will detect horizontal planes and ONLY on those horizontal planes I can place 3D objects to be motion tracked.

Is there any way (perhaps using PointCloud information) to be able to place an object in the scene even if there are no horizontal planes detected? Sort of like these examples?
https://experiments.withgoogle.com/ar/flight-paths
https://experiments.withgoogle.com/ar/arcore-drawing

I know they are using Unity and openFrameworks, but could that be done in Java?

Also, I have looked at
[How to put an object in the air?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008630/how-to-put-an-object-in-the-air)
and
[how to check ray intersection with object in ARCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017301/how-to-check-ray-intersection-with-object-in-arcore/46028084#46028084)

but I don't think I'm understanding the concept of Ancor (I managed to drop the object on the scene, but it either disappears immediately or it is just a regular OpenGL object with no knowledge about the real world.

What I want to understand is:
- How and is it possible to create a custom/user defined plane, that is, a plane that is NOT automatically detected by ARCore?
- How can I create an Ancor (the sample does it in the PlaneAttachment class, I think) that is NOT linked to any plane OR that is linked to some PointCloud point?
- How do I draw the object and place it at the Ancor previously created?

I think this is too much to ask but looking at the API documentation has not helped me at all

Thank you!

**Edit**:

Here is the code that I added to HelloArActivity.java (Everything is the same as the original file except for the lines after // ***** and before ...

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
...
        MotionEvent tap = mQueuedSingleTaps.poll();

        // I added this to use screenPointToWorldRay function in the second link I posted... I am probably using this wrong
        float[] worldXY = new float[6];
...
        if (tap != null && frame.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {

            // ***** I added this to use screenPointToWorldRay function
            worldXY = screenPointToWorldRay(tap.getX(), tap.getY(), frame);
...

        }
...

        // Visualize anchors created by touch.
        float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
        for (PlaneAttachment planeAttachment : mTouches) {
...
        }

        // ***** This places the object momentarily in the scene (it disappears immediately)  
        frame.getPose().compose(Pose.makeTranslation(worldXY[3], worldXY[4], worldXY[5])).toMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, 0);

        // ***** This places the object in the middle of the scene but since it is not attached to anything, there is no tracking, it is always in the middle of the screen (pretty much expected behaviour)
        // frame.getPose().compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -1.0f)).toMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, 0);

        // *****I duplicated this code which gets executed ONLY when touching a detected plane/surface.
        mVirtualObject.updateModelMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, scaleFactor);
        mVirtualObjectShadow.updateModelMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, scaleFactor);
        mVirtualObject.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);
        mVirtualObjectShadow.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);
...
}
```

Comment: How do you know where to place when there are no planes though? Will it be placed relative to device frame?

Comment: Also, if you managed to place something but it didn't work completely, please attach the code that "sort of works" so we can maybe point at what should be changed in that to make it work.

Comment: This is my second question actually... From what you say, It is not possible to place objects if there are no planes... But, could PointCloud points be used as Ancors and thus have a trackable object? Perhaps I am not understanding at all what PointClouds are...

Comment: @Li Xiang... Yes! When that line is used, the object remains at the same position and it does not disappear. Can you think of a way to link (x, y, z), let's say, to a PointCloud point or some other Ancor?

Comment: @AlejandroMartinez, a Point Cloud also has a Pose of some description, which you can use the same way as frame's Pose. So you could potentially use plane if it's there, otherwise falling back to the cloud and if that's not there either, then use frame. You should really check if that works in ways that's acceptable for you. I suspect a lot of jumping around with this approach.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov, Thank you for your suggestion! I have tried what you said but I could not get it to work. I started reading on WEB AR Core, specifically three.ar.js examples (https://github.com/google-ar/three.ar.js/tree/master/examples) and what do you know... There is a Spawn at Camera example which does pretty much what I need... They basically get the frame's pose (as you suggested), transform the object and ADD (this a function in three.js) it to the scene. In ARCore, there is no add, only anchors and planes. Any suggestions? Should I post a different question about this? Switch to web?

Comment: @AlejandroMartinez did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

**You would first have to perform a hit test via [Frame.hitTest](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Frame#hitTest(float,%20float)) and iterate over the HitResult objects until you hit a Point type Trackable. You could then retrieve a pose for that hit result via [HitResult.getHitPose](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/HitResult#getHitPose()), or attach an anchor to that point and get the pose from that via [ArAnchor.getPose](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Anchor#getPose()) (best approach).**

However, if you want to do this yourself from an arbitraty point retrieved with [ArPointCloud.getPoints](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/PointCloud#getPoints()), it will take a little more work. In this approach, the question effectively reduces down to "How can I derive a pose / coordinate basis from a point?".

When working from a plane it is relatively easy to derive a pose as you can use the plane normal as the up (y) vector for your model and can pick x and y vectors to configure where you want the model to "face" about that plane. (Where each vector is perpendicular to the other vectors)

[image]

When trying to derive a basis from a point, you have to pick all three vectors (x, y and z) relative to the origin point you have. You can derive the up vector by transforming the vector (0,1,0) through the camera view matrix (assuming you want the top of the model to face the top of your screen) using [ArCamera.getViewMatrix](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Camera#getViewMatrix(float[],%20int)). Then you can pick the x and z vectors as any two mutually perpendicular vectors that orient the model in your desired direction.